# ol3-cesium : drawing shape interaction in 3D?

Tags: openlayers-3, cesiumjs

I have an OpenLayers 3 application that displays maps and I want to use **ol3-cesium** to add a 3D mode.

With OpenLayers 3, I'm easily able to draw selection shape with the mouse using interaction (point, line, circle & polygon).

Now I want to do the same in 3D. I know communication is unidirectionnal between ol3 to cesium, but I was wondering if cesium-drawhelper could be integrated.

cesium-drawhelper requires the CesiumWidget object to be built. Does anyone know how to get the ref to this object in the api ?

Cheers

Comment: The starting point might be the Cesium scene object, obtained through  map3d.getCesiumScene().